# Google map is not working Properly in ajax request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Hi I have one web application where i am using google map in my site. For Fetching Marker points I am using ajax request. In First time When I am using this it's working perfect but when i tried for second time (ANY refresh). Then it's showing only half google map.
I am using version 2 google map api.
Please help me to find the solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Would be helpful to see some code. It's difficult to determine what is going wrong when we don't know how you're implementing maps and ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hard to say what is your problem here. You might want to try to redraw the map by using

```
map.checkResize();
```

or in google maps api v3:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

But this normaly shouldn't be needed...